# Exception has occurred: ImportError cannot import name 'Rescaling'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, importerror

I am trying to train deep learning models but having these error in following line:

```
 from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Rescaling
Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'Rescaling'
```

I am using these versions-

```
python 3.6.10 on Miniconda3
tensorflow-gpu=2.1.0
keras-gpu=2.2.4
cuda 11 
cuDNN=8.0.1
```

help regarding this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with tensorflow, however, tensorflow states for GPU it is a single package.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu
For releases 1.15 and older, CPU and GPU packages are separate. The version you are using looks newer.

```
pip install tensorflow  # stable
pip install tf-nightly  # preview
```

In your case the requirements.txt would be updated to have tensorflow in there instead of tensorflow-gpu.

I would start with their example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/Rescaling

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(
    scale, offset=0.0, name=None, **kwargs
)
```